Occupancy grid creation based on ultrasonic inputs in C++
Let' assume that we have a robot, 4 ultrasonic sensors on its rectangular chassis and aligned 45 degrees with respect to the robot’s axis. I also have an input file that consists more columns:
The first column is the timestamp measured in millisecond from the start, the second
column corresponds to x coordinate, the third one to the y coordinate, the fourth to the orientation
of the robot in radians. The further columns give the four ultrasonic sensors measured time of flight
in seconds.
I have no problem with reading the file, but making an algorithm that creates the occupancy map is not so easy and requires math knowledge. I share my implementation, that is not perfect I think. I would like to have reviews for this if I do something wrong and suggestions how could I make it more better.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

struct Robot
{
    float m_x{0.0f};
    float m_y{0.0f};
    float m_orientation{0.0f};
};

struct SensorSet
{
    float m_sensorA{0.0f};
    float m_sensorB{0.0f};
    float m_sensorC{0.0f};
    float m_sensorD{0.0f};
};

const float GC_GRID_SIZE = 100.f;
const float GC_CELL_SIZE = 0.1f;
const float GC_ROBOT_WIDTH = 0.1f;
const float GC_ROBOT_LENGTH = 0.2f;

int main()
{
    std::string l_fileName = "input.csv";
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> l_occupancyGrid(GC_GRID_SIZE, std::vector<unsigned int>(GC_GRID_SIZE, 0));

    //Reading the file

    std::ifstream l_file(l_fileName);

    if(false == l_file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error during file opening." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::string l_line;
    std::getline(l_file, l_line);

    while(std::getline(l_file, l_line))
    {
        std::stringstream l_linestream(l_line);
        unsigned int l_timeStamp;
        std::string l_tempData{""};
        float l_x, l_y, l_orientation, l_sensorA, l_sensorB, l_sensorC, l_sensorD;

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_timeStamp = std::stoi(l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_x = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_y = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_orientation = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_sensorA = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_sensorB = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_sensorC = std::stof (l_tempData);

        std::getline(l_linestream, l_tempData, ',');
        l_sensorD = std::stof (l_tempData);


        // Calculate the place of the robot
        Robot l_robot{l_x, l_y, l_orientation};

        SensorSet l_sensors{l_sensorA, l_sensorB, l_sensorC, l_sensorD};

        // Update occupancy grid

        float l_obstacleDistance{0.0f};
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            float l_sensorAngle = l_robot.m_orientation + (i * M_PI /4.0f);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    l_obstacleDistance = l_sensors.m_sensorA * 100;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    l_obstacleDistance = l_sensors.m_sensorB * 100;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    l_obstacleDistance = l_sensors.m_sensorC * 100;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    l_obstacleDistance = l_sensors.m_sensorD * 100;
                    break;
                default:
                    l_obstacleDistance = 0.0f;
                    break;
            }

            // Calculate obstacle position compared to the robot
            float l_obstacleX = l_robot.m_x + (l_obstacleDistance - GC_ROBOT_LENGTH /2.0f) * cos(l_sensorAngle);
            float l_obstacleY = l_robot.m_y + (l_obstacleDistance - GC_ROBOT_LENGTH /2.0f) * sin(l_sensorAngle);

            // Convert obstacle position to grid indices
            int l_gridX = static_cast<int>((l_obstacleX / GC_CELL_SIZE) + (GC_GRID_SIZE / 2.0f));
            int l_gridY = static_cast<int>((l_obstacleY / GC_CELL_SIZE) + (GC_GRID_SIZE / 2.0f));

            if (l_gridX >= 0 && l_gridX < GC_GRID_SIZE && l_gridY >= 0 && l_gridY < GC_GRID_SIZE)
            {
                l_occupancyGrid[l_gridY][l_gridX] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Output or visualize the occupancy grid
    // For simplicity, just print the occupancy grid
    for (const auto& row : l_occupancyGrid)
    {
        for (int cell : row)
        {
            std::cout << (cell == 1 ? "#" : ".");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    l_file.close();
    return 0;
}

